# Debugging iOS app built from commandline

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, debugging, gdb

I am building an app for iOS via commandline but I am having problems debugging it. Had I built using XCode, it would have let me "build and debug" on device without problems. But now, I don't know how to launch it on device using gdb and step through it. If I try to "add a custom target/executable" to a blank XCode project and then launch it, XCode complains about not finding the executable. Same thing happens if I install the app on device manually and try to attach to it using gdb within XCode. Any pointers on how to go about debugging this app? Changing the build process to use XCode is not an option.

Comment: Are you trying to debug on the device or in the simulator?

Comment: I am trying to test it on device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This site](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Debugserver) gives a nice tutorial on how to manually set up a remote debugging session on an iOS device.  The process boils down to creating a remote debugging server on the device and attaching to it with a local GDB instance.

Comment: Thanks. Seems promising. I guess there is no chance that I will be somehow able to launch gdb from within XCode? Would love to have a GUI interface to gdb.

Comment: When you hit build and run in xcode it does the steps that site describes automatically.  I'm currently using Xcode 3 so these shortcuts have probably changed, but if you hit cmd+shift+y you can bring up the graphical debugger, or if you prefer a normal gdb console hit cmd+shift+r.  xcode has a graphical breakpoint manager too which you can show with cmd+option+b.